# How to schedule a task automatically with a while loop in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to schedule my script to run at two different times and then keep running in the background waiting for the next time that the conditions are met again.

So far I am not able to do it because after that one condition is met this scripts exits automatically:

```
function schedule {

while :
do
    hour=$(date +"%H") 
    minute=$(date +"%M")

    if [[ "$hour" = "02" && "$minute" = "31" ]]; then
        # run some script
        exec /home/gfx/Desktop/myscript.sh
        wait
        schedule

    elif [[ "$hour" = "02" && "$minute" = "32" ]]; then
        # run some script
        exec /home/gfx/Desktop/myscript.sh
        wait
        schedule
    fi 

done

}

schedule
```

The script that I execute is the following :

```
$cat myscript.sh
echo "this a message"
```

Any idea or comment are welcome, thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with cron?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```
 exec some program
 something else
```

if the exec works, then the `something else` will never happen because the script is replaced by what you exec'd

Maybe instead of:

```
exec /home/gfx/Desktop/myscript.sh
wait
schedule
```

you want:

```
/home/gfx/Desktop/myscript.sh &
wait
# schedule  -- don't make a fork bomb
```

As noted in the comments, `& + wait` is kind of silly, you probably want:

```
/home/gfx/Desktop/myscript.sh &
# wait
# schedule
```

or:

```
/home/gfx/Desktop/myscript.sh
# wait
# schedule
```

depending on whether or not you want myscript in the background.

**ALSO** you should put a sleep in the loop, (maybe `sleep(59)`) to keep it from looping like a banshee.

You begin to understand the appeal of cron I think (at least for things you don't want to interact with your terminal session).

Comment: The program will then become a **fork bomb** because `schedule` will spawn additional copies of itself. Thus, while this is a correct answer, it is also a dangerous answer at the moment. Anyway, agree with the consensus that the OP should probably be using `cron` anyhow.

Comment: Also, running a background program and then immediately calling `wait` is equivalent to not running it in the background.

Comment: I figured they had a reason for the wait.  But perhaps not.  Anyway, made it clearer you don't want to re-call yourself (fork-bomb).

Answer (score 1):

Crontabs are best place to put these things.

- Edit crontab using

  $ crontab -e
- Add following lines to the files

```
31 2 * * *  /home/gfx/Desktop/myscript.sh
```

And save crontab file. Your script will be executed every day 2:31 am

Comment: Linux `cron` allows you to put `31,32` in the minutes field, to achieve exactly what the OP seems to be trying to do.

Comment: in fact the script that i call in the loop first it sendme a mail with the command sendmail to know when the script starts, as well at the end it sendme another mail to know when the scripts ends, but when y execute "myscript.sh" with cron it does not sendme the mail when my script starts and when my script finish, only do the other code inside of my script, for that reason cron is not a option for me